# Button overflow x in line when the screen is mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I have a line with buttons. When I reduce the screen I want all the buttons to remain in line and work as an overflow-x: scroll.

My problem is that when reducing the screen, the overflow x works, but the button comes out of the screen.

How can I solve this? Thanks

[DEMO](https://www.codeply.com/p/KK1oxJ1z3w)

**CODE**

```
  <div class="row justify-content-center flex-nowrap myrow" style="margin-top: 160px;">
    <a style="color: #51CC8B;" class="btnP">PRG
      <span class="nav-link btn-glyphicon1">100</span>
    </a>
    <a style="color: #4981C2;" class="btnR">TRV
      <span class="nav-link btn-glyphicon">50</span>
    </a>
    <a style="color: #4981C2;" class="btnD">DN
      <span class="nav-link btn-glyphicon">21</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

**Problem**

[image]

Comment: so you would want to be able to scroll on X on the buttons ?

Comment: @ MihaiT , 
Yes, the problem is that the buttons are coming off the screen and I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed `row` class
and
added `d-flex justify-content-md-center` classes
and added below css

```
.myrow {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```css
.myrow {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.btn-glyphicon {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: #ffffff;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #DBE7F4 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #4981C2;
}

.btn-glyphicon1 {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: #ffffff;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #DDF6E9 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #51CC8B;
}

.btnR {
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 13px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 6px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #4981C2;
  -ms-border-radius: 16px;
  -o-border-radius: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius: 16px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border-width: none;
  background: #ECF2F9;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.btnP {
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 13px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 6px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #51CC8B;
  -ms-border-radius: 16px;
  -o-border-radius: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius: 16px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border-width: none;
  background: #EDFAF3;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.btnD {
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 13px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 6px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #4981C2;
  -ms-border-radius: 16px;
  -o-border-radius: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius: 16px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border-width: none;
  background: #ECF2F9;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-md-center flex-nowrap myrow" style="margin-top: 160px;">
  <a style="color: #51CC8B;" class="btnP">PRG
      <span class="nav-link btn-glyphicon1">100</span>
    </a>
  <a style="color: #4981C2;" class="btnR">TRV
      <span class="nav-link btn-glyphicon">50</span>
    </a>
  <a style="color: #4981C2;" class="btnD">DN
      <span class="nav-link btn-glyphicon">21</span>
    </a>
</div>
```